# how to resize an image to fit the label size? (python)

Tags: python, image, tkinter

My aim is to create a random country generator, and the flag of the country that is picked will appear. However, if the image file is bigger than the predetermined size of the label, then only part of the image is displayed. Is there a way of resizing the image to fit the label? (All other questions like this which I have seen have been answered, mentioning the PIL or Image modules. I tested them both, and they both came up with this error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\country.py", line 6, in 
    import PIL
ImportError: No module named 'PIL'**

This is my code, if it helps:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random

flags = ['England','Wales','Scotland','Northern Ireland','Republic of Ireland']

def newcountry():

    country = random.choice(flags)
    flagLabel.config(text=country)
    if country == "England":
        flagpicture.config(image=England)
    elif country == "Wales":
        flagpicture.config(image=Wales)
    elif country == "Scotland":
        flagpicture.config(image=Scotland)
    elif country == "Northern Ireland":
        flagpicture.config(image=NorthernIreland)
    else:
        flagpicture.config(image=Ireland)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Country Generator")

England = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="england.gif")
Wales = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="wales.gif")
Scotland = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="scotland.gif")
NorthernIreland = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="northern ireland.gif")
Ireland = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="republic of ireland.gif")
blackscreen = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="black screen.gif")

flagLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="",font=('Helvetica',40))
flagLabel.pack()

flagpicture = tkinter.Label(root,image=blackscreen,height=150,width=150)
flagpicture.pack()

newflagButton = tkinter.Button(text="Next Country",command=newcountry)
newflagButton.pack()
```

The code works perfectly fine apart from only showing part of the image. Is there a way to resize the images within the code itself?(I am using Python 3.5.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have PIL installed, first you need to install

```
pip install pillow
```

Once installed you can now import from PIL:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Tk's PhotoImage can only display .gif's, whereas PIL's ImageTk will let us display various image formats in tkinter and PIL's Image class has a `resize` method we can use to resize the image.

I trimmed your code down some.

You can resize the image and then just configure the label, the label will expand to be the size of the image. If you gave the label a specific height and width, lets say `height=1` and `width=1` and you resized the image to be 500x500 and then configured the widget. It would still display a 1x1 label since you've set these attributes explicitly.

In the below code, modifiying the dict, it is not okay to modify a dict while iterating over it. dict.items() returns a copy of the dict.

There's various ways to do this, I just though a dict was convenient here.

[Link to an image that's over the height / width limit](https://media.giphy.com/media/fts60w6387eus/giphy.gif)  - kitty.gif

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 150, 150
flags = {
    'England': 'england.gif',
    'Wales': 'wales.gif', 
    'Kitty': 'kitty.gif'
}

def batch_resize():

    for k, v in flags.items():
        v = Image.open(v).resize((WIDTH, HEIGHT), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        flags[k] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(v)

def newcountry():

    country = random.choice(list(flags.keys()))
    image = flags[country]
    flagLabel['text'] = country
    flagpicture.config(image=image)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    root.configure(bg='black')

    batch_resize()

    flagLabel = Label(root, text="", bg='black', fg='cyan', font=('Helvetica',40))
    flagLabel.pack()

    flagpicture = Label(root)
    flagpicture.pack()

    newflagButton = Button(root, text="Next Country", command=newcountry)
    newflagButton.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of randomly selecting a country to display its flag, we loop through the flags dictionary that is key-sorted. Unlike the random choice which will inevitably repeat the flags, this scheme runs through the countries in alphabetical order. Meanwhile, we resize all the images to a fixed pixel size based on the width and height of the root window multiplied by a scale factor. Below is the code:

```
import  tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class   Flags:

    def __init__(self, flags):
        self.flags = flags
        self.keyList = sorted(self.flags.keys()) # sorted(flags)
        self.length = len(self.keyList)
        self.index = 0

    def resize(self, xy, scale):
        xy = [int(x * y) for (x, y) in zip(xy, scale)]
        for k, v in self.flags.items():
            v = Image.open(r'C:/Users/user/Downloads/' + v)
            v = v.resize((xy[0], xy[1]), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.flags[k] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(v)

    def newCountry(self, lbl_flag, lbl_pic):
        country = self.keyList[self.index]
        lbl_flag["text"] = country
        img = self.flags[country]
        lbl_pic.config(image = img)
        self.index = (self.index + 1) % self.length # loop around the flags dictionary

def rootSize(root):
    # Find the size of the root window
    root.update_idletasks()
    width = int(root.winfo_width() * 1.5)      #   200 * m
    height = int(root.winfo_height() * 1.0)    #   200 * m
    return width, height

def centerWsize(root, wh):
    root.title("Grids layout manager")
    width, height = wh
    # Find the (x,y) to position it in the center of the screen
    x = int((root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - width/2)
    y = int((root.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - height/2)
    root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(width, height, x, y))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    flags = {
        "Republic of China": "taiwan_flag.png",
        "United States of America": "america_flag.gif",
        "America": "america_flag.png",
    }

    root = tk.Tk()
    wh = rootSize(root)
    centerWsize(root, wh)
    frame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=5, relief=tk.GROOVE)
    frame.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=3)
    flag = Flags(flags)
    zoom = (0.7, 0.6)   # Resizing all the flags to a fixed size of wh * zoom
    flag.resize(wh, zoom)
    lbl_flag = tk.Label(frame, text = "Country name here", bg = 'white', fg = 'magenta', font = ('Helvetica', 12), width = 30)
    lbl_flag.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    pic_flag = tk.Label(frame, text = "Country flag will display here")
    pic_flag.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
    btn_flag = tk.Button(frame, text = "Click for next Country Flag",
                         bg = "white", fg = "green", command = lambda : flag.newCountry(lbl_flag, pic_flag))
    btn_flag.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PIL(pillow module to resize the image)

But in order to resize the images to exactly to the widget size, You can do the following. (Assuming that you are familiar with basic tkinter syntax structure)

```
your_widget.update() #We are calling the update method in-order to update the 
#widget size after it's creartion, Other wise, it will just print '1' and '1' 
#rather than the pixel size.

height=your_widget.winfo_height()
width=your_widget.winfo_width()
print(height,weight)
```

Now you can use the height and width information to create a new image that you can size it perfectly to your widget.

But if you have your image is already created, you can use the PIL module to resize the image to your size

first open your image with

```
flag_temp = Image.open("file location")
```

next resize the image to your size

```
flag_new = flag_temp.resize((10,10))# example size
```

make your final image to add in your widget

```
flag_final = ImageTk.PhotoImage(flag_new)
```

now you can use the 'flag final' varible in your widget.

IF YOUR APP HAS TO BE RESIZED AT ANY POINT, you can use the height and width varible created in the first code para, to dynamically resize the image
But you should make sure that the function is called regularly to update it.

You should also pass in the height and width variable in the place of (10,10) something like this

```
flag_new = flag_temp.resize((height,widht)
```

Hopefully this was helpful, I think the answer is bit long for your question, If you have any problems pls comment below.